# R dplyr: exclude single combination pair of values after frequency check-up

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I would like to remove the combinations having a single value pair in a selected column.

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(sample(LETTERS[1:2],99,replace = TRUE),LETTERS[6]), 
                 b=sample(letters[1:10],100,replace=TRUE))
```

Chekcing the counts of different combinations:

```
df %>% group_by(a, b) %>% summarise(count=n()) %>% data.frame()
#    a b count
# 1  A a     9
# 2  A b     4
# 3  A c     4
# 4  A d     2
# 5  A e     4
# 6  A f     2
# 7  A g    12
# 8  A h     6
# 9  A i     6
# 10 A j     7
# 11 B a     3
# 12 B b     5
# 13 B c     5
# 14 B d     5
# 15 B e     3
# 16 B f     8
# 17 B g     3
# 18 B h     6
# 19 B i     1
# 20 B j     4
# 21 F g     1
```

I can remove the single frequency of combination pairs such as below using `%>% filter(n() > 1)`

```
#    a b count
# 19 B i     1
# 21 F g     1
```

But, I want to remove only the following pair irrespective of their frequency i.e., 1 or more than 1. The reason for not removing the `B-i` pair is that B still have other combination pairs(with a, b, c, d, e ,f, g, h).

```
#    a b count
# 21 F g     1
```

Expected output:

```
#    a b count
# 1  A a     9
# 2  A b     4
# 3  A c     4
# 4  A d     2
# 5  A e     4
# 6  A f     2
# 7  A g    12
# 8  A h     6
# 9  A i     6
# 10 A j     7
# 11 B a     3
# 12 B b     5
# 13 B c     5
# 14 B d     5
# 15 B e     3
# 16 B f     8
# 17 B g     3
# 18 B h     6
# 19 B i     1
# 20 B j     4
```

i.e., remove the combination `F-g` which has only one combination for value in column `a`.

Scenario 2:

```
df2 <- data.frame(c=c(1,2,4,6,8,3), d=c(2,3,5,7,9,5),
                 e=c('a1','a2','a3','a4','a5','a5'),
                 a=c('F','F','F','F','F','F'),
                 b=c('a','b','a','b','a','a'))

#   c d  e a b
# 1 1 2 a1 F a
# 2 2 3 a2 F b
# 3 4 5 a3 F a
# 4 6 7 a4 F b
# 5 8 9 a5 F a
# 6 3 5 a5 F a

df2 %>% group_by(a, b) %>% filter(n()>2)
# Source: local data frame [4 x 5]
# Groups: a, b [1]
# 
# # A tibble: 4 x 5
# c     d      e      a      b
# <dbl> <dbl> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr>
# 1     1     2     a1      F      a
# 2     4     5     a3      F      a
# 3     8     9     a5      F      a
# 4     3     5     a5      F      a

df2 %>% group_by(a, b) %>% filter(n()>2) %>% summarise(count=n())
# Source: local data frame [1 x 3]
# Groups: a [?]
# 
# # A tibble: 1 x 3
#     a      b count
# <fctr> <fctr> <int>
#     F      a     4
```

Comment: For the second case, what is your expected output `df2 %>% count(a, b)`

Comment: Expected output is empty! I will be getting data from other values of  `a` which is not shown here.

Comment: It is not clear for me.  Here the `df2 %>% count(a, b)` gives two rows of 'F' and according to your logic, it should not be deleted.  It seems like you have a new logic

Comment: Did you meant `df2 %>% group_by(a, b)  %>% filter(n() >2 & n_distinct(a,b) > 1)`

Comment: This command is taking considerable amount of time. When I split the filter statements, they are not working separately.

Comment: May be it is the `n_distinct` (it is from dplyr though).  Try `setDT(df2)[, .SD[.N >2 & uniqueN(a,b)>1], .(a,b)]` from `data.table`

Comment: it gives the error `Error in forderv(x, by = by, retGrp = TRUE, na.last = if (!na.rm) FALSE else NA) : 
  'by' value -2147483648 out of range [1,1]` I have to look into this.

Comment: What is your data.table version.  I used `data.table_1.10.5`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149464/discussion-between-prradep-and-akrun).

Comment: Sorry, the chat window is not loading.  I am at work place(so probably some restrictions)

Comment: @akrun I am currently using `data.table` version 1.10.4

Comment: Ok, then it might be a case where you have only NA for a specific group

Answer (score 1):

After we get the `count`, do a group by on 'a' and `filter` the rows where the number of rows is greater than 1

```
df %>%
    count(a, b)  %>%
    group_by(a) %>% 
    filter(n()>1)
```

NOTE: `count` can replace the `group_by/summarise` step

---

On big datasets, it may be better to do the `filter` first and then do the `count`

```
df %>% 
    group_by(a) %>%
    filter(n() >1) %>% 
    count(a, b)
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't try to replicate the scenario well. I have tried to put it in a clear way in scenario 2. Could you please check and advise?